# UEFI Dual Boot partitioning with 14.04 and Win 8.1 on SSD + HDD

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, uefi, ssd, secure-boot

I'm setting up a new machine with a SSD and a HDD. Windows is for gaming and Ubuntu for working. I'll install 8.1 first and leave 10GB on the SSD for /. On the HDD I'll leave 120GB for /home and the equivalent of my RAM for swap. The rest of the space on the HDD is gonna be NTFS and shared by Windows and Ubuntu.
I'll turn off fast boot in Windows.
What else do I need to take care of when in the "something else" menu during install? Can I leave the bootloader with its default setting? Can I leave secure boot enabled?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you install in EFI mode, you must ensure that you have an [EFI System Partition (ESP).](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EFI_System_partition) Windows should create this ***IF*** you install it in EFI mode before you install Ubuntu. That's not guaranteed, though; depending on your firmware settings, getting the right boot mode can be a gamble. I recommend leaving BIOS/CSM/legacy support turned *off* in the firmware to help simplify the boot path and ensure both your installers boot in EFI/UEFI mode. The details of how to do this, and even precisely what similar-sounding options do, vary greatly from one system to another, though. For more on this subject, see [my Web page on CSMs.](http://www.rodsbooks.com/efi-bootloaders/csm-good-bad-ugly.html)

Also, I personally would create an ESP, and perhaps other partitions, ahead of time *before* installing Windows. Windows creates a smallish (100MiB, IIRC) ESP by default. This is usually fine, but the ESP should be FAT32, and a few EFIs have problems with such small FAT32 partitions -- files can become mysteriously "invisible," which makes boot loaders malfunction. I recommend an ESP of 550MiB, which is big enough to avoid these problems. Note that the ESP doesn't really need to be on the SSD; the files it holds are small, and they're accessed just at boot time or when upgrading them, so the performance gain from putting the ESP on an SSD will be tiny.

Aside from the ESP and the fact that EFI-based computers generally boot from [GUID Partition Table (GPT)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GUID_Partition_Table) disks, Linux partitioning needs don't vary from BIOS-mode to EFI-mode installations. You plan sounds basically reasonable, although I'd give a little more than 10GiB to root (`/`). Although a bare-bones Ubuntu installation takes only about 6GiB, IIRC, there are any number of reasons why it might grow above that. I'd say 20-30GiB is reasonable, assuming you can spare the disk space. (I know it's an SSD, so space may be a bit tight there.)